# Browse Qt sources in Qt Creator (in Windows)

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qt5.5

Can't switch to class implementation when browsing Qt header. Forced to manually search for it in file browser. Is there a way to switch to Qt class implementation when browsing its header by F2, F4, etc?

Comment: Did you open it as a whole project, or just the header file?

Comment: Just header which referenced in my project.

Comment: If you just opened the header, how is QtCreator supposed to know where to find the functions to it?

Comment: I know that, however good to have some option like "Qt sources". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for now: open qt.pro with all the sources in Qt Creator with my current project, in this case Qt Creator able to browse sources, however not all - can't get to private classes, does not navigate into some methods. Still need to do this manually